# How to fill all missing values (across all columns) in a DataFrame based on their group averages?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame with missing values across some numerical columns:

```
             Region       Country  Job Satisfaction  Generosity    Family
25           Africa  South Africa              61.3         NaN  1.384789
43   Eastern Europe  North Cyprus               NaN         NaN  1.186303
61           Africa   South Sudan               NaN    0.285671       NaN
78   Western Europe   Switzerland              93.7    0.290549  1.516912
91   Western Europe         Italy              85.5    0.172790  1.444923
104  Eastern Europe      Slovakia              81.4    0.136544       NaN
```

How can I fill these missing values using the country's associated region's mean for the given column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `mean` omit non numeric columns you can simplify solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df.update(df.fillna(df.groupby("Region").transform('mean')))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, select all numerical columns using `df.select_dtypes(np.number)`
2. On all numerical values, you can now use `transform()` to fill the values as desired, using `groupby("Region")` and then `x.mean()` so that average of groups are used.
3. Finally, update the original `df` using `pd.DataFrame.update()` so that original numerical columns are all overwritten by the new ones.

```py
df.update(
    df.select_dtypes(np.number).transform(
        lambda series: df.groupby("Region")[series.name].transform(
            lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())
        )
    ),
)
```

Which gives:

```py
print(df)

#              Region       Country  Job Satisfaction  Generosity    Family
# 25           Africa  South Africa              61.3    0.139362  1.384789
# 43   Eastern Europe  North Cyprus              81.4    0.266846  1.186303
# 61           Africa   South Sudan              61.3    0.285671  0.601323
# 78   Western Europe   Switzerland              93.7    0.290549  1.516912
# 91   Western Europe         Italy              85.5    0.172790  1.444923
# 104  Eastern Europe      Slovakia              81.4    0.136544  1.505059
```